# RegEx to get all text after 's.' and remove all

Tags: php, regex

```
$element = "Lorem ipsum s. any text";
// the result should be:
$m[1] = "any text";
$element = "Lorem ipsum";
```

First I would like to get all text after `s.` for further processing. Second I need to remove this including the `s.` 
Therefore I'm using `preg_replace_callback`.

My problem is to get the correct RegEx:

**PHP:**

```
$regex = "??";
$result = array();
$element = preg_replace_callback($regex, function ($m) use (&$result) {
    $result[]=$m[1];
    return '';
}, $element);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex for matching:

```
^(.+?)s\. *(.+)$
```

And grab captured group #1 and #2

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yE7yS4/1)

#### Code:

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum s. any text";  
if (preg_match('/^(.+?)s\. *(.+)$/', $str, $m)) {
   echo "part1=$m[1], part2=$m[2],"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$re = "/s\\.(.*)/mi";
$str = "Lorem ipsum s. any text\n";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/pE9bV5/3)

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
$element = "Lorem ipsum s. any text";
$pattern = '#(s\..*)#i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $element, $matches);
print 'matched : ' . $matches[1][0] . "\n";
print 'clean text : ' . str_replace($matches[1][0], '', $element);
```

hope that helps :)